# Android Device Compatibility

Tags: android

how do i come to know which device is compatible to be overhauled with Android OS.
I wanted to know what is the basic hardware requirement.

thanks

Comment: Question is confusing to me =/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you've got the requirements: http://source.android.com/compatibility/
You also can download the current CCD there to have a look into the requirements.